# Parse (iOS): Set custom class pointer property

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

If I have a custom class in Parse, and I have the subclasses in xcode, how do I make the property for a pointer?

For example, this is how you would do it for a file and for a number:

```
@property (retain) PFFile *imagefile;
@property (retain) NSNumber *rank;
```

Classes in Parse dashboard:

Class 1: name (string), imagefile (file)

Class 2: imageid (Pointer (Class 1 row))

Comment: Do you mean PFObject?

Comment: Yes I do know Objective-C

Comment: Every instance is pointer.

Comment: Yes but when you set a "Pointer" in Parse dashboard, what would you use in the custom class in xcode

Comment: I do not know what you mean. About properties usage？

Comment: Have you created a column in Parse dashboard with pointer type (to a file in another class)? Then try to subclass that custom class in xcode?

Comment: Show the subclass definition you say you have

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Parse pointer for example a Parse class named **Article**, then first you have to have it subclassed in Objective-C (name it `Article`) and add the property to your containing class like:

```
@property (retain) Article *article;
```

UPDATE:

The `Class2` property would look like this:

```
@property (retain) Class1 *image;
```

When you fetch a `Class2` query, you can include the key for `image`, so you can load both the parent and the image row at once:

```
PFQuery *query = [Class2 query];

// Include the image data
[query includeKey:@"image"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
      Class2 *firstRow = [objects firstObject];
      NSLog(@"Image URL %@", firstRow.image.imagefile.url);
      // ...
    }
}];
```

Comment: It's not pointed to another class it is pointed to a PFFile in another class

Comment: Please update the question with the classes, so we can get a clearer picture.

Comment: Updated it. Check now

Comment: What about the ObjC class names?

Comment: Class 1.h/Class 1.m Class 2.h/Class 2.m?